# Use XSLT to format XML elements into HTML in sets of two

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the following XML dataset (simplified), where I can have from zero to endless items (usually there will be 2-10):

```
<item template="event_element">
   <mytitle>This is the first title</mytitle>
   <mydate>20110330T143004</mytitle>
   <mydescription>This is the first description</mytitle>
   <mylink>www.example.com</mytitle>
</item>
.
.
<item template="event_element">
   <mytitle>This is the Tenth title</mytitle>
   <mydate>20110330T143004</mytitle>
   <mydescription>This is the tenth description</mytitle>
   <mylink>www.example.com</mytitle>
</item>
```

My end result should be like this, where I can end up with several sets of items (which will be rotated by javascript):

```
<div class="body">
<div class="rel" id="arrangement">

    // First set of items goes here
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itm">
            <div class="in">
                <p>
                    <a href="MY LINK" title="MY LINK DESCRIPTION">
                        <span>MY DATE</span>
                        <strong>MY FIRST TITLE</strong>
                        MY SHORT DESCRIPTION...
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="itm last">
            <div class="in">
                <p>
                    <a href="MY LINK" title="MY LINK DESCRIPTION">
                        <span>30. mar 2011</span>
                        <strong>MY SECOND TITLE</strong>
                        MY SHORT DESCRIPTION...
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>

    // Second set of items goes here
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itm">
            <div class="in">
                <p>
                    <a href="MY LINK" title="MY LINK DESCRIPTION">
                        <span>MY DATE</span>
                        <strong>MY THIRD TITLE</strong>
                        MY SHORT DESCRIPTION...
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="itm last">
            <div class="in">
                <p>
                    <a href="MY LINK" title="MY LINK DESCRIPTION">
                        <span>30. mar 2011</span>
                        <strong>MY FORTH TITLE</strong>
                        MY SHORT DESCRIPTION...
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

My problem is stepping through my items (that should even be sorted by the date desc) and grouping them in sets of two.

As it is today I have been forced to hardcode the sets like this (the $eventfolder, $totalevents variables have been predefined):

```
<pre><code><div class="body">
  <div class="rel" id="arrangement">
    <xsl:if test="$totalevents &gt; 0">
      <div class="item">
        <xsl:for-each select="$eventfolder/item[@template='event_element' and position() &gt; 0 and position() &lt; 3]">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() &lt; $eventsperpage">        
          <div class="itm">
            <xsl:call-template name="renderEvent" />    
              </div>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
          <div class="itm last">
            <xsl:call-template name="renderEvent" />    
              </div>
              <div class="clr"></div>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>     
      </div>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$totalevents &gt; 2">
      <div class="item">
        <xsl:for-each select="$eventfolder/item[@template='event_element' and position() &gt; 2 and position() &lt; 5]">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() &lt; $eventsperpage">        
          <div class="itm">
            <xsl:call-template name="renderEvent" />    
              </div>
            </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
        <div class="itm last">
          <xsl:call-template name="renderEvent" />  
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>       
    </div>
  </xsl:if>

   <div class="clr"></div>
 </div>
</div>
</code></pre>
```

The renderElement template simply renders the inside event HTML.

But that way is not very practical if I wanted to show more sets than 2 - or even show more items in each set... The xslt file would be big and unreadable...

Any help to how I can solve this problem, since I cant figure out how to insert HTML tags as the XSLT compiler cant see them being closed - ie. (when `test="position() = 1` insert html start tag and then later when `test="position() = X` close the tag).

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add your current xslt so we may better advise, it sounds like you are attempting to create output tags based on position in a list instead of applying a template!

Comment: 't was there, only Markdown & the OP didn't play nice together :)

Comment: On a side note: might be a good thing to add hEvent classes / tags to this thing for SEO if it's public.

Comment: thanks for fixing the view of the code ;)

Comment: http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page to find more information about the hEvents

Comment: still not the full code here to see!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

> Any help to how I can solve this
>   problem, since I cant figure out how
>   to insert HTML tags as the XSLT
>   compiler cant see them being closed -
>   ie. (when `test="position() = 1` insert
>   html start tag and then later when
>   `test="position() = X` close the tag).

You're thinking about the problem wrong. XSLT generates trees, not tags. You create elements, not halves of elements.

The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!--  the number of items to include in each group -->
    <xsl:variable name="group" select="2" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="events/item[@template='event_element']
                               [(position() - 1)  mod $group = 0]" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[@template='event_element']" mode="inner">
        <div class="itm">
            <div class="in">
                <p>
                    <a href="{mylink}" title="{mydescription}">
                        <span><xsl:value-of select="mydate" /></span>
                        <strong><xsl:value-of select="mytitle" /></strong>
                        <xsl:value-of select="mydescription" />
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[@template='event_element']">
        <div class="item">
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select=".|following-sibling::item[@template='event_element']
                                                 [position() &lt; $group]"
                mode="inner" />
            <div class="clr" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this input:

```
<events>
<item template="event_element">
   <mytitle>This is the first title</mytitle>
   <mydate>20110330T143004</mydate>
   <mydescription>This is the first description</mydescription>
   <mylink>www.example.com</mylink>
</item>
<item template="event_element">
   <mytitle>This is the second title</mytitle>
   <mydate>20110330T143004</mydate>
   <mydescription>This is the tenth description</mydescription>
   <mylink>www.example.com</mylink>
</item>
<item template="event_element">
   <mytitle>This is the third title</mytitle>
   <mydate>20110330T143004</mydate>
   <mydescription>This is the tenth description</mydescription>
   <mylink>www.example.com</mylink>
</item>
<item template="event_element">
   <mytitle>This is the fourth title</mytitle>
   <mydate>20110330T143004</mydate>
   <mydescription>This is the tenth description</mydescription>
   <mylink>www.example.com</mylink>
</item>
<item template="event_element">
   <mytitle>This is the fifth title</mytitle>
   <mydate>20110330T143004</mydate>
   <mydescription>This is the tenth description</mydescription>
   <mylink>www.example.com</mylink>
</item>
</events>
```

Produces the following output:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="itm">
        <div class="in">
            <p>
                <a href="www.example.com" title="This is the first description">
                    <span>20110330T143004</span>
                    <strong>This is the first title</strong>
                    This is the first description
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="itm">
        <div class="in">
            <p>
                <a href="www.example.com" title="This is the tenth description">
                    <span>20110330T143004</span>
                    <strong>This is the second title</strong>
                    This is the tenth description
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="itm">
        <div class="in">
            <p>
                <a href="www.example.com" title="This is the tenth description">
                    <span>20110330T143004</span>
                    <strong>This is the third title</strong>
                    This is the tenth description
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="itm">
        <div class="in">
            <p>
                <a href="www.example.com" title="This is the tenth description">
                    <span>20110330T143004</span>
                    <strong>This is the fourth title</strong>
                    This is the tenth description
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="itm">
        <div class="in">
            <p>
                <a href="www.example.com" title="This is the tenth description">
                    <span>20110330T143004</span>
                    <strong>This is the fifth title</strong>
                    This is the tenth description
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr" />
</div>
```

Change the number of items to include in each group by modifying the value of the `group` variable.

Comment: Correct approach for sequence partition, but remember that variable/parameter references are not allowed in XSLT 1.0 patterns.

Comment: @Alejandro - I consistently forget this. Updated to remove the variable ref from the `match`.

Comment: Thanks, this answer actually solved my first problem in a better way than my own code. (i cant give +1 because i dont have enough rep yet). But my next problem is of cause how to get the events sorted by date - cause if I use a sort it will only sort in pairs of 2's (sets).  
If I cant get the events sorted I may have to resolve to using C# or hacking the XSL with xsl:text and disabling-output-escaping to create start and end tags according to position().

Comment: @Barnebarn - So, you want them sorted by date and then grouped?

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the larger issues raised by your approach, in XSLT the way to group a list of elements n elements at a time is this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[(position()-1) mod $n = 0]" mode="group"/>
```

...which will apply the group-mode template to the first, n+1th, 2n+1th, etc. child elements of the current element.  The group-mode template looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="group">
   <group>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
           select=".|following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $n]"/>
   </group>
</xsl:template>
```

This creates a `group` element, and within that element, applies templates to the current element and its n-1 following siblings.

The net effect is that as long as n is a positive integer, the above will create `group` elements containing n consecutive elements from the source tree.  In your example, you'd create a `div` instead of a `group`, among other changes.

Comment: Correct. `position() mod $n = 1` would be more simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="items">
<div>
<xsl:apply-template select="item"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:apply-templates match="item">
do stuff here
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

are you using something similar to this?

Comment: Im not best of friends with the comment or code editing here atm ;)
But the above code is in the main template and it is called with the root of the xml and only calls the renderEvent template for each events as shown in the code.